# Httppostedfilebase always null in controller

Tags: controller, asp.net-mvc-5, httppostedfilebase

I know this question is asked many time, and i search for the answer but I am deffinetly missing something..

My View..

```
@using TaxiAssistant.Views.CompanyAdmin.Resources

@using (Html.BeginForm("ImportDrivers", "CompanyAdmin", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) {

    <input type="file" name="uploadFile" id="file1" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="@Resources.Import" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div> 
}
```

My controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ImportDrivers(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {


            return View();
        }
```

In controller parameter is always null. What am I missing :/

Comment: Lol...and with this inside controller I can access posted file ..  var uploadedFile = Request.Files[0]; wtf ??

Answer (score 3):

Change the name of the method parameter to match the name of the control

```
<input type="file" name="uploadFile" id="file1" />

public ActionResult ImportDrivers(HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile)
{
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this inside your Controller

```
file = Request.Files["uploadFile"];
```

and you wll have your uploaded file in **file** object of HttpPostedFileBase